# Insert 2nd auto increment id for multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I want to insert same auto increment id for multiple rows. Currently,I am using the default auto increment is. how can I add 2nd auto increment id (same id ) for multiple rows in another column? As I am using `groupid` in the following code. .

```
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST['array'] as $key => $array) {
    $data[$key]['groupid'] = intval($array['groupid']);
    $data[$key]['User'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['user'])));
    $data[$key]['address'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['address'])));

}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users ('groupid','user','address') VALUES (:groupid, :user, :address) ");
foreach ($data as $key => $array) {
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':groupid' => $array['groupid'],
        ':user' => $array['user'],
        ':address' => $array['address'],
    ));
}
```

Comment: There are a few errors in the script as it stands - missing close quote in `['User]` and you would need to use backticks round column names instead of single quotes - `'groupid'` etc.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for this? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. What do you mean by “2nd auto increment id” - MySQL creates a new ID for each row when using autoincrement, if you do not want that don't use autoincrement.

Comment: @feeela as mentioned in the question above that i am currently using 1 auto increment id. i want one more auto increment id 1 for all rows of loop data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is beyond the scope of `auto_increment`. I don't know of an SQL feature that allows this, you would need to write the logic yourself in the application.

Try this:

- `SELECT MAX(groupid) FROM users`
- Save the result as a PHP variable
- Add one (+1) to that variable
- Use the variable in your `INSERT` statement for the `groupid`.